# Задача: Сделать брутфорс MD5 хеша для картинки

Tags: c#, bitmap

Задача: Имеется **png** изображение и слепая зона этого изображения -  Rectangle(0, 0, 8, 8), нужно изменяя пиксели(rgba) в слепой зоне найти момент, когда все байты изображения при переводе в хэш MD5 будут выдавать 8-16 нулей в начале, важно именно сделать сам метод, а не высчитать хэш с множеством нулей(Это уже я сам как-нибудь высчитаю :))

Под задача c которой у меня проблемы, суть:
Есть Bitmap(8, 8) ака (Color[8,8]), все пиксели в нём - (0,0,0,0).

Нужно сделать счётчик через него, пример на пальцах:
1:
int: 23752₁₀    5CC8₁₆     92,200₁₆₋₁₀
Color: Color(92, 200, 0, 0) (Остальные все должны быть Color(0, 0, 0, 0)) 
2:
int: 3938237298632864₁₀   DFDCE5339E8A0₁₆   223,206,83,57,232,160₁₆₋₁₀
Color: Color(223, 206, 83, 57), Color(232, 160, 0, 0)

Так же должен быть метод, который добавляет 1 к этому счётчику, из `Color(223, 206, 83, 57) + 1` получается `Color(224, 206, 83, 57)`, а из `Color(255, 206, 83, 57) + 1` получится `Color(0, 207, 83, 57)` 
Это всё bitmap 8x8, `y` считается как `x * y`, то есть (x = 0, y = 1) по счёту Color будет иметь своего образный 9 индекс.
Должно работать быстро + работать только с Color(В виде bitmap), то есть не использовать множество превращений связанных с byte[] и int, использовать что-то около SetPixel и GetPixel(Не очень разбираюсь в оптимизации с bitmap)
Надеюсь что задачка интересная, хоть и сложная из-за запрета превращений.

Comment: Задача сводится к перебору всех возможных значений пикселей чтоли? Тогда `Color` не нужен раз человекочитаемость цвета не важна. 8 x 8 x 4 = 256 байт = 2^2048 итераций, и чтобы перебрать все значения. Скажем там, даже при самых быстрых реализациях - это слегка не быстро получится. Но вы дали, насколько я понял только маленькую часть задания. И никакого смысла. Что делать с этим дальше, в каком виде оно будет использоваться? Возможно нужна многопоточка, вот только ее не реализовать правильно не зная, куда девать то что нагенерилось.

Comment: Без этой части задачи я ничего не могу дальше делать.
Вы можете просто сделать форму, где будет выводится этот Color и постоянно увеличиваться. 
Мне в будущем это нужно будет для перебора картинок, мне нужно одну картинку немного изменять её чтобы в какой-то момент сгенерировать хэш MD5 с 8-16 нулями в начале, дело не быстрое, но я не тороплюсь.
Я буду менять пиксели с помощью вашего способа и этого счётчика.

Comment: Напишите это в сам вопрос. Теперь хоть понятно, что это нужно для хэширования. Как вы раньше указывали, хэш выполняется из пожатой картинки PNG, это тоже напишите. Если я дам код, хоть будет понятно, почему он такой. Мой способ + счетчик будет примерно раз в 1000 медленнее, чем то что я хочу написать. Так что выкладывайте всю суть задачи прямо в текст вопроса, тогда его может не закроют как непонятный до того как я дам ответ.

Comment: Так просто больше шанс на ответ, ибо разбираться в доп вещах не всем интересно/не хочется. А так минимум что у меня не получается я выложил

Comment: Нет, не так, сейчас ваш вопрос идет на закрытие как непонятный, я бы не зная смысла даже разбираться бы не стал. А знаю как раз за счет того что отвечал на ваш прошлый вопрос. Ваше право оставить все как есть, я лишь дал совет.

Comment: @aepot, обновил, нормально?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть вот такая заготовочка, которая считает ~10к хэшей с PNG в секунду.

Сам счетчик.

```
public unsafe class BitmapGenerator : IDisposable
{
    public readonly Bitmap Bmp;
    private readonly BitmapData _data;
    private readonly uint* _ptr;
    private readonly int _length;
    private bool _disposed;

    public BitmapGenerator(int width, int height)
    {
        Bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        _data = Bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, Bmp.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, Bmp.PixelFormat);
        _ptr = (uint*)_data.Scan0;
        _length = width * height;
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;
        _disposed = true;
        Bmp.UnlockBits(_data);
        if (disposing)
            Bmp.Dispose();
    }

    public bool Next()
    {
        int offset = 0;
        while (offset < _length && unchecked(++_ptr[offset]) == 0)
            offset++;
        return offset < _length;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~BitmapGenerator() => Dispose(false);
}
```

Здесь осторожней, битмап, который он возвращает, припинен в памяти, его нельзя изменять, только сохранить и все. Такое опасное поведение сделано ради производительности.

Проверяем

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string dir = "png";
        // с помощью этого закомментированного кода я проверял, действительно ли хэши картинок правильные
        //foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(file));
        //    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToHexString(MD5.HashData(File.ReadAllBytes(file))).ToLower());
        //}
        //return;
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        using var generator = new BitmapGenerator(8, 8);
        using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using var md5 = MD5.Create();
        Span<byte> hashBuffer = stackalloc byte[16];
        double count = 0;
        int success = 0;
        const int threshold = 5;
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        do
        {
            generator.Bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            ReadOnlySpan<byte> data = ms.GetBuffer().AsSpan()[..(int)ms.Position];
            ms.Position = 0;
            md5.TryComputeHash(data, hashBuffer, out _);
            if (GetStrength(hashBuffer) >= threshold)
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(dir, Convert.ToHexString(hashBuffer.ToArray()).ToLower() + ".png"), data.ToArray());
                success++;
            }
            count++;
            if (count % 1000 < 1)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                Console.WriteLine($"{count:F0}");
                Console.WriteLine(success);
                Console.WriteLine($"{count / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds:F1} hash/sec   ");
                if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    Console.ReadKey(true);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (generator.Next());
    }

    private static int GetStrength(ReadOnlySpan<byte> hash)
    {
        int strength = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
        {
            if (hash[i] == 0)
            {
                strength += 2;
                continue;
            }
            if ((hash[i] & 0xf0) == 0)
                strength++;
            break;
        }
        return strength;
    }
}
```

Вроде работает, пример вывода в консоль:

```
953000
1
9536,1 hash/sec
```

Пример найденного хэша для порога в 5 нулей: `0000094ca808ce04dffae7f8cbfaac99`. Картинку крепить не буду, на такой ранней стадии у первого пикселя альфа `0`, то есть несмотря на то что картинка содержит данные, она полностью прозрачна.

Если вам нужно 8 нулей, ставьте `threshold = 8` и ждите. :) Скорость 10к/сек конечно далека от идеала, на моих 8 ядрах можно как раз ускорить на потоках раз в 8. Плюс еще провести всякие оптимизации, например написать свою супербыструю реализацию MD5 на SIMD векторах, но это уже не тривиальные задачи. Так же можно сохранять и загружать состояние генератора в виде той же картинки. Но для начала вам и этого хватит.

Comment: Спасибо большое.     
1) ох вектора в ускорителях... оххх.
2) StopWatch быстрее DateTime.Now - DateTimeStart?
3) Вы ещё не учли что тут нет много поточности, я потом изменю ваш ответ, посмотрите, правильно ли я сделал многопоточность

Comment: @Yotic 1) :) 2) Stopwatch внутри как раз DateTime использует, так что спорный вопрос 3) здесь нет многопоточки, я предоставил это вам. :) если у вас будет вопрос про многопоточку, лучше задать его отдельно. Ну и не спешите с этим, да.

Comment: Я так подумал, что мне многопоточность не очень нужна, т.к у меня нет дедлайна, как например на мой первый майнер. Я просто размещу его на бесплатном дедике и забуду на пару месяцев.

Comment: @Yotic если дедик 2-3-4-зеоновый, то вы это очень зря. Так бы на многопоточке во все 256 ядер зарядить можно было. :)

Comment: @Yotic и вывод в консоль пореже сделайте, раз в 100, а если проц мощный, то в даже в 1000.

Comment: Сделал раз в 100 секунд, так же я удалил часть кода, т.к мне не просто нули нужны, а прям байты, впринципе не очень большая проблема бы была. Сделал что от 3 нулевых байтов изображения кидаются в отдельные папки, в зависимости от количества нулевых байтов

Comment: Дедик бесплатный на 1 ядро на год

Comment: @Yotic если ядро одно, то это не дедик, а виртуалка :) дедик - это кусок железа, нода, полностью под вашим контролем со всей начинкой, не виртуалка. Так что не путайте. Одноядерных дедиков я уже лет 20 не видел вживую.

Comment: Да, есть у меня такая проблема, очень часто вообще любой сервер называют дедиком, нужно отвыкать

Comment: @Yotic `Сделал раз в 100 секунд` у меня раз в 1000 хэшей было, если по секундам, можно было хоть раз в 10 секунд.

Comment: Сейчас протестировал, я когда ставлю изображение в приложение, а после его скачиваю, то у меня получается другой хеш и совсем другого вида изображение
https://pastebin.com/KG8zdeVD
Думаю нужно воевать с EncoderParameter