# Получить настройки png-изображения

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь получить настройки енкодера, с помощью которого было сохранено png-изображение (на севере).
Мне нужно понять, как было сохранено png-изображение, чтобы изменить пару пикселей и сохранить его в таком же виде и сразу же получить хеш, который будет на сервере.

Пытался использовать: DirectXTexNet, SixLabors.ImageSharp, Aspose.Imaging, GDI+ (но к сожалению там нельзя использовать png при EncoderParams).
Так же перебирал 100000 вариаций сохранения с помощью SixLabors.ImageSharp, что ничего не дало.

Как для теста можно просто скачать изображение и попытаться его сохранить с такой же последовательность байтов (можно понять по хешу)

Comment: GDI+ `System.Drawing` тоже не катит?

Comment: Странно что банальные libpng и imagemagick не попробовали — если сервер линуксовый, то с 99% вероятностью использовалось что-то из этих двух

Comment: В тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1381702/373567

Comment: Нет, я делал тест, просто подгружал и сохранял одно и тоже изображение в цикле, так я получал:\
(исходное) X9BA -> D00A\
D00A -> F0FA\
F0FA -> F0FA\
F0FA -> F0FA

Comment: Вообще я друга попросил написать тему, ибо у меня уже более месяца запрещено писать вопросы (было -8 репутации, сейчас уже -2 (странно)).

Comment: @aepot,
Этот способ не работает, т.к при загрузке на сервер картинка на нём декодируется и кодируется в другое изображение (с такими же пикселями), то есть я не могу получить заранее понять, какой хеш будет на сервере

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо, сейчас попытаюсь на них написать

Comment: @alexandr951, libpng имеет только Decoder и мало настроек. Magemagick же имеет намного больше настроек, но всё-же не способен сохранить изображение в том же виде, в каком загрузил. Так же заметил что Magemagick сохранил изображение так же, как это сделал System.Drawing

Comment: В libpng конечно же есть и всегда был энкодер, возможно у вас биндинги к сишарпу какие-то кривые